# Rectifier circuit with unexpected output

Tags: power-electronics, simulation, proteus, igbt

[image: Output]

I am developing a circuit using Proteus 8.

My aim is to get a full wave (discrete) sine output to the load. I use an IGBT to switch the full wave rectified signal and get output in pulse form (purple output in oscilloscope.)

My issue is I do not get the expected output to the lamp.

This is the expected output:

[image: expected output to the lamp]

Schematic:

[image: Schematic]

I have connected 2 probes to oscilloscope and measured the signal before the lamp and after the lamp (yellow signal and blue signal outputs.)

- Why are these two outputs different?
- Why I don't get a full wave signal as output?

(Original Google Drive link to the images is [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NNKVjBKjI9iAgmM6AjovFFCgfJgqkjmU?usp=sharing).)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113662/discussion-on-question-by-jithma-senarathne-rectifier-circuit-with-unexpected-ou).

Answer (score 1):

You are not looking at the lamp voltage, but at two points relative to ground (VF1, VF2). What you see is right.
[image: három]

If you really look at the voltage of the lamp, it will look the way you expected it to:
[image: egy]

[image: kettő]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Can you explain why these two points relative to ground (VF1, VF2) show negative part as zero ?

Comment: The negative half of the rectifier is grounded, so relative to the ground, from which we can only see positive signals.

Comment: The 230VAC N is already grounded, so you may not connect ground as depicted in your schematics.

Comment: Yes that's true. Here, an isolating transformer is missing from the beginning of the schematic. It will only make the 230V generator ground independent.